# Question askers tend to mark high-rep users' answers as answer

Tags: discussion

I notice this a lot that many questions have similar answers but the question asker mark the answer of a high-rep user as answer (sometimes other answers are better than the high-rep user answer), and the answer is also get a lot of upvotes. Why this happens and What should we do when this happens?

Comment: Ummm... because the user has high rep?

Comment: my main point is that the fact that the user is a high-rep user should not bias the question asker to accepting it's answer or upvoting it @BoltClock

Comment: Could you please provide some examples? I don't doubt you've seen this happen, but perhaps the answers aren't as similar as you think?

Comment: OK, we get it. If you want to add an entire list, feel free to edit your question.

Comment: I saw at least 2 answers with just code and no explanation. If I wasn't feeling all happy today, that'd have meant a downvote from my part. Don't assume your answers are better (or even good) in everyone's eyes.

Comment: Your votes are your own. And so is everyone else's

Comment: Relate from meta.programmers.SE: [Why always answers of users who have the maximum reputation in a question accepted and voted up?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/5870/40980)

Comment: and that question is +6 and mine is -6! :D @MichaelT

Comment: @dotctor different meta sites, different cultures, different times, different people voting.  The MSO culture often has a "we've heard this before, downvote" aspect to it. And they've got a point there - 8k questions since the MSO/MSE split (and MSE is nearly 70k). Meta.P.SE is 1.8k since the beginning. Many questions on M.P.SE are still novel (not all, we've got our "yea, we heard that before, please have something new" too). If people perceive it as something they've heard before or another person 'whining' it tends to get down votes. Don't worry about it - meta doesn't have rep changes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first two you linked to, i think the other answer was indeed better. In [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388340/sorting-object-list-is-not-working/27388466#27388466), you just say "try this" and give some code, while the other user explained it. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27391430/calling-the-methods-of-an-object-instantiated-in-one-method-from-another-method/27391458#27391458), you did explain, but apparently the OP found the other one better.

[These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827285/parse-string-contains-time-of-day/26827358#26827358) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783640/c-sharp-console-application-is-there-a-way-to-enter-number-without-them-showing/26783732#26783732) i think you did write well; +1 from me.

Timing matters too - often it will just be the first answer that gets accepted.

But in the end, it's all up to the asker to decide which one helped them the most. And yes, it is possible that some people prefer to accept high-rep users' answers, due to perceived better knowledge.

Myself, if it's a choice between upvoting a high-rep user and a low-rep user, i'll give the lower user the +1 if the answers are of equal value.

Comment: I think it may be partly a matter of each question's OP making a quick decision. In the third and fourth cases the final form of @dotctor's answer looks good, and got upvoted accordingly, but the version that existed at the time of the high-rep accepted answer was significantly different. Even if the accept is done later, there is at least as likely to be bias in favor of the first acceptable answer as in favor of high-rep users.

Comment: +1 for "*if it's a choice between upvoting a high-rep user and a low-rep user, i'll give the lower user the +1 if the answers are of equal value*", though upvoting and accepting as an answer are not quite the same.